# Is there a security concept that protects data send from a server to an client?

Tags: java, security, server, client, communication

I am currently working on an project where I have to control some hardware depending on the output of some sonsors. The Software is up and running + everything is fine except I have some security concerns.

The current concept is that the client pc (located at customer) collects the data from the sensors, sends it to my server. The server processes the data and send some Integer values as an response to the client. Those are used to control some external Hardware from the customer...

Now I am concerned that some customer maybe captures the processed Integer values (they are a big part of the business logic and very valueable).

I wonder if there is another concept where i dont have this kind of problem or maybe some other kind of security improvement.

The only requirement is that the client pc must stay at the customers place.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You could simply use SSL/TLS.

Comment: If you need to encode the communication, SSL is indeed a good option, if you use http(s). But obviously you will need have your own http server in this case with some REST or SOAP API. If you use SSL, you will need to generate your certificates and sign them too. If you are not using certification authorities recognized by the JDK, you will need to have these in separate keystores. So there is quite a bit of overhead typically to SSL.

Comment: Thanks guys, that should be it.